# Using a CMS as a dynamic presentation engine

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, presentation

I need to prepare a business presentation that will be shown on several monitors in the company.

This presentation will show both static contents (essentially HTML pages and images) and dynamic charts that are updated periodically. These charts are created loading data from a production DB, so a little programming effort should be required.

The presentation should be managed by people with little (or nothing at all) technical expertise (e.g. sales employees, etc.)

As in classical presentations, there should be a timed transition between pages.

At the moment, an ad-hoc web application is used. It's a very basic application not so easy to handle for "non programmers".

Is it possible to get something like that, using programs such as Power Point or similar?
Or, alternatively, is there some dedicated CMS for this case of use?

**UPDATE**
I tried using PowerPoint like suggested in the comments, but this solution update data in the presentation only at opening time... Instead I nead data to be updated every time the slide is shown.

**MORE DETAILS**
The data to be shown are stored on a MS SQL Server 2005 database. These data should be represented by pie charts and histograms (currently we use Google Charts). The development of the graphics page is entrusted to IT office, so there are no problems about that. The issue is that in the presentation will also be present commercial contents, this part of the work is entrusted to sales office, which has no expertise in information technology. The application currently in place has not been developed to be used by non-programmers. The presentation will loop on some monitors connected to the same machine (**no internet connection provided**) and not require any user operation. We are currently using IE8.

Comment: Any CMS require some work to be deployed and managed. http://prezi.com/ is relatively easy-to-use, WYSWYG and nice. It could do the job. regards

Comment: @vaugham thanks for the suggestion, but the presentation will run on a machine that isn't connected to the internet...

Comment: I have never used it, but there is an offline presentation functionality. You may download the work you've done online.

Comment: It looks like Powerpoint can import data from databases to put into charts. I've never tried it myself.

Comment: @DavidRichard is there some example or reference you can suggest me?

Comment: http://www.jegsworks.com/lessons/presentations/advanced/step-importdata.htm or http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/present-sales-reports-in-powerpoint-HA001085785.aspx  This works if your data is in an excel sheet. You will need to import the data into excel first (silly that it requires to steps but that's what it seems to be)

Comment: So, to clarify, the actual presentation needs to be easy to use for the people viewing it, correct? What is the level of expertise on the person managing the presentation? Also, what type of database is the data stored in? SQL, mySQL? Also, what sort of cross-browser compatibility is required if you go the webpage route? IE8, IE9, chrome, firefox?

Comment: @DavidRichard I've edited the question, adding more details

Comment: I know this question is rather old, but the mystery had gone unsolved. I just saw a presentation application called sliderocket that lives in the cloud and can pull dynamic data from google spreadsheets. Maybe that would work?

Comment: Thank you @DavidRichard. The project is paused at the moment, but I'm actually still looking for a solution, so I'll take a look to SlideRocket. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Prezi.com](http://prezi.com/) is very nice like vaugham mentioned.  Very slick! You will like it and it can be exported/downloaded to use as a standalone presentation.

Comment: the main issue is showing dynamic data (basically charts), can Prezi do it?

Comment: I have not used it like that.  Contact Prizi (someone might have asked them something similar).  Could you just create a very current snap shot of the events you are conveying to your people? and make it into an image?  In my own toolbox, I use Coldfusion for presentation requests because I can do real-time charts (bar graphs and charts), using flash extensions built right in.  You may be down to the wire on a solution so picking up a programming language may not be feasible, but it may help if you find yourself approaching something like this in the future.  I hope this is somewhat helpful.